# Does sifr flash display the fonts if they are not installed in the pc?

Tags: php, flash, fonts, sifr, oscommerce

I want to use the Sifr functionality with the Margarosa font and so i have created my sifr swf with the required margarosa font.
This works fine and the effect is visible properly in my pc as the margarosa fonts are installed in my computer.
But when i check it in another computer where these fonts are not installed, the effect is not displayed in it.
To get an idea plz check the link below:

http://www.flowerbottle.co.uk/index.php?cPath=61&osCsid=06khdrtp172fklsidbmrb75ke2.

Check the heading there where i have used the sifr flash.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It should, but after a quick glance at your Javascript source code the only SWF sIRF file you seem to be including is tradegothic.swf. I'd suggest you to [try this wizard](http://www.sifrgenerator.com/wizard.html) and update your JS files.